# When opening the flag menu (To flag a question, answer) then scrolling down, The flag menu does not move

Tags: support, user-interface, flag-dialog, close-dialog

So I wanted to flag a question, I wanted to take another look at the side of the question by scrolling down, then the flag menu disappeared, I scrolled up and it was back.
Is this a bug? Or a feature?

Comment: What do you mean by “disappeared”? Did it disappear suddenly or did it just scroll along with the page?

Comment: Yes, it's not relative. It seems to be fixed off the top of the window when it's loaded. Scroll back up and it'll be there. Or down, depending on with way it vanished :) I'm going to guess that no matter what.. it's going to be status-by-design ;)

Comment: You can drag the flag window around using the top area (where it says "I am flagging to report this question as...").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "disappearing". The "flag" and "close" dialogs scroll with the page. You can drag them around manually by grabbing onto the header with your mouse (*e.g.*, to move them out of the way of content that you're trying to figure out how to flag), but, normally, these dialogs scroll along with the other content in the viewport.

This behavior makes sense to me: the dialogs are associated with the *content* which you're considering flagging or voting to close, and thus the dialogs should move along with that content.

I strongly suspect that this is by design and not a bug.